# Google Analytics code not showing in Magento 2 page code

Tags: magento, cookies, google-analytics, magento2

I want to add Google Analytics in my Magento 2 shop. I added the Tracking ID to `Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Google API`. Now, I should see the GA tracking code after the opening `body` tag on every page in my magento shop. That is not the case. I read that the cookie restriction mode disables the code as long as the user doesn't accept the cookie warning. After that the page reloads and the code should be there. But it still isn't. Because of the EU cookie guidelines I can not disable the cookie restriction mode or force the page to load the GA code by hardcoding it into every page. I've seen people in several forums who had the exact same issue but it all got stuck in some point with no answer provided.

Has anyone a solution for this problem? Because I really need to track my traffic and audience.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest implementing Universal Analytics via Google Tag Manger.
I use [this extension](https://github.com/magepal/magento2-googletagmanager) to manage the implementation of GTM and the dataLayer for enhanced e-commerce tracking.

Comment: Maybe you have missed any step in its implementation. Well, you can refer this guide: https://magenticians.com/add-google-analytics-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Magento 2.2.5
What fixed this for me was

`bin/magento cache:flush`

Also I have the General > Web > Default Cookie Settings
Cookie Restriction Mode: No

There is a fix mentioned on the github issue or update to Magento 2.2.6 if you want to have the Cookie Restriction because EU is Cookie Monster.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14951